# How to keep new row in RadGridView on clicking away twice

Tags: c#, winforms, radgridview

I am using radGridView in winforms application with add new row functionality on save button click and leaving new row. It saves new row if some required values are provided otherwise it stays there.

The problem is that when I am adding new row and required values are not entered and I click away it performs ideally, it doesn't save and stays there but on second click away removes new row. I want to keep new row even we click away multiple times.

Comment: What have you already tried. StackOVerflow helps to fix your code not to write it for you.

Comment: I used UserAddingRow event handler to control clicking away or leaving new row situation. This event handler is triggered when we click away first time and works fine according to my logic new row stays there if it is not empty. Issue is when i already have clicked away and i click again somewhere else, new row is lost. I wan to keep new row on multiple clicks away.

Comment: You rather meant `UserAddedRow` not Adding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow?view=netframework-4.8 but I guess it's only a typo. You just have to add this condition to your code `when i already have clicked away and i click again` and eg. ignore the event to do your logic. Suddenly without this specific part of code your code I can't tell more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, my friend the condition is already there that's why its working fine on first click away from new row. but the problem is on second click when i am already away. it doesn't trigger the UserAddingRow.

Comment: I have used UserAddingRow because i had to use e.cancel to cancel the operation to keep the new row there.